# Which .JAR do I use to embed Jetty?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets, jetty

I'm at the point in my application where I would like to have an HTTP Server embedded into my project that updates the page in real-time using AJAJ(Similar to AJAX). However, I have no idea where to begin and the amount of tutorials on this subject are fairly limited, so I decided to go with a name that I've heard quite a few times before, **Jetty**

So, I downloaded Jetty and read through some documentation, and I'm staring at their beginner tutorial asking myself, "Which one of these f*kin jars do I use?" There's like 9,001 of them. Not to mention that there's like 1200 folders that all contain 1500 more jar files each.

Okay, I'm over exaggerating, but take a look.

[image]

It's fairly, uhm...  confusing. This is much different than most libraries that are a single jar file, this is just... insane.

Anyway, I'm trying to figure out what all I need to be able to use JQuery, AJAX(AJAJ), and basic HTML features.

Comment: I am guessing you will be needing more than a single jar here. Jetty server might be dependent on other java libraries as well. I would recommend using Maven or similar tool to resolve jar dependencies.

Comment: I don't understand Maven, and after spending three days trying to convert my project over to it (That uses nearly 15 different .jar libraries) I gave up.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to start with this simple tutorial and `jetty-all` jar

- [Embedding Jetty Webinar recording](http://vimeo.com/19146453)
- [Embedding Jetty docs](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty)
- [jetty-all different versions downlad](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/aggregate/jetty-all/)

Comment: +1 for the links,
I'll mark it correct if I get it working from the webinars, I found the jetty-all.jar, however it was throwing classnotfound exceptions.

I'd assume it's because my project isn't in maven format, but... 
I don't dependencies in maven, and I'm using numerous .jar libraries that I'm dependent on.

Comment: @Christian.tucker since you are using windows, you'll need to make adjustments to the jetty-all examples to suit your environment.  (such as using `;` instead of `:` in any sort of PATH-like variables, like classpath)

Answer (score 0):

To followup on Gas's answer.

jetty-all doesn't have 100% of Jetty.

It used to, hence the name.

However, today its impossible to have 100% of jetty, as many components can conflict with each other.

If you use maven, or gradle, or ant+ivy, then you'll likely want to depend on:

- `org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp`
- `org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-server-impl`

*let the transitive nature of those build tools pull in the rest.*

This would get you "started" easily enough.

There are also plenty of example projects that use embedded jetty.

See:

- [Embedded Jetty: with JSP enabled](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp)
- [Embedded Jetty: with various WebSocket configurations](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-websocket-examples)
- [Embedded Jetty: using Servlet 3.0 features](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-servlet-3.0)
- [Embedded Jetty: using Servlet 3.1 features](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-servlet-3.1)
- [Embedded Jetty: various Logging configurations](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-logging-examples)

Some use 100% embedded jetty (without a war file, or WEB-INF, or web.xml), some use a war file built elsewhere.

Jetty uses maven so it can participate in the global central artifact repository, and that we have 2 developers on Jetty that are also developers on Maven.

If you want to manage the dependencies yourself, then you will *need to know intimately* the purpose and role/purpose/relationship/requirements of every jar file that you are going to add into your project.  (and answering that is *way out of scope for stackoverflow*)

You have many build tool options to make managing the dependencies easier:

- [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)
- [Gradle/Grails](http://www.gradle.org/)
- [Apache Buildr](http://buildr.apache.org/)
- [Apache Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) (an add-on for Apache ant)
- [Groovy Grape](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape)
- [Scala SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org/) (for working with Scala on top of Java)
- [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/) (for working with Clojure on top of Java)

Maven isn't required, you could use any of the above tools.

Tip: Maven and Gradle are the best integrated in various IDEs (like Eclipse IDE and IntelliJ)

Comment: Could you explain the difference between the file types? My problem has commonly been since I don't use Maven I'm having problems with Tomcat/Jetty. Not to mention all of the guides show you how to set it up through maven and nothing else.

Comment: The file types are all jars.  not sure what you are asking.

Comment: "war, web-inf, web.xml" were the file types -- all of the examples you provided use a MAVEN setup, which my project doesn't use. My issue is getting Jetty to run without maven.

Comment: The answer tells you that there are some examples with and some examples without those files (war, web-inf, web.xml).  You should really know intimately what those files are before you attempt to use any embedded web container.  Also, just saying "embedded jetty" doesn't mean there is only 1 way to do things.  In fact the number of ways to do something with embedded jetty is so numerous that it is essentially infinite.  There is also no "best way", "suggested way", or "common way".  As all techniques are valid, some projects just have different goals the want to reach.